Is it illegal to not have an ID that FinCEN wants?
Under the Corporate Transparency Act, which is coming into full force this year, many corporate entities are required to report beneficial owner information to FinCEN for major shareholders or important executives. According to FinCEN's FAQ, a beneficial owner who "willfully causes a reporting company’s failure to submit complete or updated beneficial ownership information to FinCEN" can be held liable, which could lead to "criminal penalties of up to two years imprisonment and a fine of up to $10,000".
This is fine, except that one of the required pieces of information is an ID number from one of:


A non-expired U.S. driver’s license (including any driver’s license issued by a commonwealth, territory, or possession of the United States);
A non-expired identification document issued by a U.S. state or local government, or Indian Tribe;
A non-expired passport issued by the U.S. government; or
A non-expired passport issued by a foreign government (permitted only when an individual does not have one of the other three forms of identification listed above).


Worth noting also is that FinCEN only takes these reports online, and to my knowledge will not allow a report to be submitted without one of these numbers entered for each owner, making it impossible to submit a report describing the situation where an owner exists but does not actually hold any ID on this list.
But it is easy for such a situation to arise (anyone can let their driver's license expire), and the only way for a company to get out of it would be for the offending owner to go get or renew one of the acceptable types of ID (or else somehow stop being a beneficial owner).
If a reportable beneficial owner of a corporation willfully refuses to get or renew at least one form of ID that FinCEN accepts, can they be criminally prosecuted?


If a reportable beneficial owner of a corporation willfully refuses to get or renew at least one form of ID that FinCEN accepts, can they be criminally prosecuted?

Yes. There's a sanction of $500 per day penalty and potential jail time.
See the page 15 of the FinCEN guide:

The willful failure to report complete or updated beneficial ownership information to FinCEN, or
the willful provision of or attempt to provide false or fraudulent beneficial ownership information
may result in a civil or criminal penalties, including civil penalties of up to $500 for each day that
the violation continues, or criminal penalties including imprisonment for up to two years and/or
a fine of up to $10,000. Senior officers of an entity that fails to file a required BOI report may be
held accountable for that failure.

This is codified in 31 USC 5336(h)(3)(A):

(3) Criminal and civil penalties.—
(A) Reporting violations.—Any person that violates subparagraph (A) or (B) of paragraph (1)—
(i) shall be liable to the United States for a civil penalty of not more than $500 for each day that the violation continues or has not been remedied; and
(ii) may be fined not more than $10,000, imprisoned for not more than 2 years, or both.



But it is easy for such a situation to arise (anyone can let their driver's license expire), and the only way for a company to get out of it would be for the offending owner to go get or renew one of the acceptable types of ID (or else somehow stop being a beneficial owner).

That seems to be the requirement. At least one of these documents should exist (passport for foreigners or a state DL/ID or a US passport for US persons). While there's no requirement in the US to have any kind of ID, this law seems to impose such a requirement as a condition for being a beneficial owner of an entity. It is unclear if such a requirement would hold up in court, but it exists as of now.

While there may be no requirement in the US to have any kind of ID, requiring an ID in order to do many things is OK. Driving, flying, opening a financial account, getting a notarized signature, ...
